# See when Macports was last updated?

Tags: macports, launchd

I recently created a launchd that updates and upgrades my macports every sunday night while I'll sleep. I'm currently trying to find out if there is a way to know when macports was last updated? I'd like to know if my launchd is truly working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing Macports has to do when updating is synchronising the ports.
These are in `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports`.
The modification date of this directory can tell you when the ports were last synchronised.